# I don't have Chromium, but the Software Updater keeps updating some extensions!

Tags: 14.04, update-manager, chromium, synaptic, ubuntu-mate

I have Ubuntu Mate 14.04, in case it matters. The Software Updater keeps giving me updates for some Chromium extensions, but I don't even have Chromium. The only browser I have currently installed is Firefox.

I checked the Synaptic Package Manager, searching for "chromium" in the quick filter. It says I have the two following packages:

Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser (chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra)

Web browser engine for Qt (codecs) (oxideqt-codecs-extra)

Is there another application using these packages? How can I tell? Should I remove them??

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: do you use gnome desktop?

Comment: yes I use gnome desktop

Comment: I had a problem with gnome extension integration, so I installed an extension called `chrome-gnome-shell`. I don't know if this can help you

Comment: I will check into this. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell if you can remove safely a package I will chose to use apt in shell. Run:

> as @mook765 says using -s option will be a better choice to prevent any mistake

```
apt-get -s remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra oxideqt-codecs-extra
```

And you can see if there are dependencies that are gonna be resolved by removing packages u wanna keep or installing new ones

```
$ sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra oxideqt-codecs-extra 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'chromium-browser' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bbswitch-dkms linux-headers-4.4.0-93 linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-93-generic
  nvidia-prime
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  oxideqt-codecs
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  oxideqt-codecs-extra
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  oxideqt-codecs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 648 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1.118 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Better to use the `-s`-option with apt-get, this will just simulate the action. This will prevent removing packages while accidentally hitting `Enter` as `Y` is the default answer in `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

Comment: So true, but im not used to do it xD